# Can i create shape programmatically

Tags: java, android, shapes

How to create shape (rectangle) in java(not in XML)  and then set him as background for button.

I need set shape  as background for  button.

Here is shape **frame.xml**:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
             android:topRightRadius="10dp" 
             android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
             android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Then in **MainActivity.java** :

```
btnDown.setBackground(getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame);
```

When i start program i have exactly what i need:

I can not post screen(small reputation)

But after i hide application, or Home button, and then back to application i have some artifacts: shape on background occupy just half of button space

I try set background in xml, `setBackgroundDrawable()`  ,`setBackgroundResourse()`, but button didn't display correct.

Comment: Did u tried anything about it, any code ?

Comment: `btnDown.setBackground(getResourse() ...` ... Resour**s**e?!! this will never work. Please check your spelling.

Comment: Sorry i have bad english spelling. This i write myself (not copy/past from code).

Comment: You can draw anything by using the draw* methods of the Canvas object.

Comment: I must create custom button extends Button?

Comment: A custom View is not really needed, if you don't plan to change the image over time. You could simply create a bitmap out of the canvas once and use that bitmap.

Comment: Thank you. But can you tell why such artifact happen?

Comment: It's weird. It normally works without any glitches. Note: if you don't explicitly address me (@Rotwang), I won't be notified of your messages. I don't need to, because you're the Original Poster (the question owner).